# Get screen size in flutter without having to pass context and without layout builder in flutter after deprecation of MediaQueryData.fromWindow()?

Tags: flutter

How can I get screen size in Flutter without passing context after the deprecation of `MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window)`. The new alternative method recommended by flutter is `MediaQueryData.fromView(View.of(context)).size.width` which involves the passing of context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'height' here  would return the same value as MediaQuery.of(context).size.height without context:

```
final double physicalHeight = WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.views.first.physicalSize.height;
final double devicePixelRatio =
      WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.views.first.devicePixelRatio;
final double height = physicalHeight / devicePixelRatio;
```

Comment: Kudos. This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't need the "screen size" in any location where context is not available.

And you don't need MediaQuery either.  Use LayoutBuilder, which gives you the **pixels remaining** in your current layout, which is the only number you should be looking at when making layout breakpoint decisions.

Comment: I am already using layout builder for different screen width breakpoints, but still MediaQuery is needed to make widgets responsive completely for a certain screen type. For instance, in the case of mobile screens, they could also differ in dimensions. And using `MediaQuery.of (context).size.height or width` in every widget is a lot of pain, so this is why I am looking for a solution with global scope

Comment: Then you should be using flex widgets (Row, Column, Expanded, etc) to do layout.  You still don't need pixels.

Comment: "you shouldn't need" type answers are not answering the question. there may be other usages than layout decisions (which obviously are typically done in presence of a context), e.g. deciding on whether the device is a tablet or not (imo there is no process that changes a tablet into a phone device of vice versa - ie this can be decided before any components are built using a mechanism that is non-reactive - as opposed to a media query which causes components to be rebuilt)